# StoreKit purchase failing - com.apple.accessibility.gax.backboard

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, storekit, skpaymenttransaction

I'm working on custom StoreKit handler class for buying an in-app purchase.

I'm having strange error, when trying to purchase something. Looks like some Apple private stuff is involved. The receipts in SKPaymentQueue's transactions are not valid. What am I doing wrong?

```
   2014-12-19 20:30:59.286 testapp[2185:624771] |AXIPC|warning| Could not send simple message (com.apple.accessibility.gax.backboard). Port:27139. Error:268435460 (0x10000004). 
<AXIPCMessage: 0x1740655c0>. Client port: 0. Key: 13012. Payload: {
    GAXIPCPayloadKeyMessageServiceName = "com.apple.accessibility.gax.client";
    GAXIPCPayloadKeyPid = 2185;
}
2014-12-19 20:30:59.289 testapp[2185:624771] |error| could not send message to backboard: notify backboard frontmost app did change (Error Domain=AXIPC Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Could not send simple message (com.apple.accessibility.gax.backboard). Port:27139. Error:268435460 (0x10000004). 
<AXIPCMessage: 0x1740655c0>. Client port: 0. Key: 13012. Payload: {
    GAXIPCPayloadKeyMessageServiceName = "com.apple.accessibility.gax.client";
    GAXIPCPayloadKeyPid = 2185;
}" UserInfo=0x174064d00 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=Could not send simple message (com.apple.accessibility.gax.backboard). Port:27139. Error:268435460 (0x10000004). 
<AXIPCMessage: 0x1740655c0>. Client port: 0. Key: 13012. Payload: {
    GAXIPCPayloadKeyMessageServiceName = "com.apple.accessibility.gax.client";
    GAXIPCPayloadKeyPid = 2185;
}})
2014-12-19 20:31:11.742 testapp[2185:624771] |AXIPC|warning| Could not send simple message (com.apple.accessibility.gax.backboard). Port:27139. Error:268435460 (0x10000004). 
<AXIPCMessage: 0x17026cec0>. Client port: 0. Key: 13012. Payload: {
    GAXIPCPayloadKeyMessageServiceName = "com.apple.accessibility.gax.client";
    GAXIPCPayloadKeyPid = 2185;
}
2014-12-19 20:31:11.743 testapp[2185:624771] |error| could not send message to backboard: notify backboard frontmost app did change (Error Domain=AXIPC Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Could not send simple message (com.apple.accessibility.gax.backboard). Port:27139. Error:268435460 (0x10000004). 
<AXIPCMessage: 0x17026cec0>. Client port: 0. Key: 13012. Payload: {
    GAXIPCPayloadKeyMessageServiceName = "com.apple.accessibility.gax.client";
    GAXIPCPayloadKeyPid = 2185;
}" UserInfo=0x170077dc0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=Could not send simple message (com.apple.accessibility.gax.backboard). Port:27139. Error:268435460 (0x10000004). 
<AXIPCMessage: 0x17026cec0>. Client port: 0. Key: 13012. Payload: {
    GAXIPCPayloadKeyMessageServiceName = "com.apple.accessibility.gax.client";
    GAXIPCPayloadKeyPid = 2185;
}})
```

Comment: I originally wrote an answer about this going away after moving out the SKPaymentTransactionObserver to a separate class from a View Controller, but I must have just got lucky a few times in a row, the problem eventually returned - made no difference if I made the App Delegate the observer or a dedicated class.

Comment: @Toby thanks for your comment. I have a separate singleton class as an observer and that happens too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im having the same problem here. But my purchases are going trough, and everything works fine, except these annoying errors.

Here its happening occasionally, does it happend every time for you, and doesnt your purchases go trough ?

The stuff im testing with it has already been bought, so i get the message if i want to restore the purchase. I even get these error messages sometimes when i press no to cancel the purchase.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Purchases are eventually going through! It tends to happen exactly when "Sign-in to continue" popup is visible and I tap on cancel button.